# Adding virtual host to nginx using IP and folder

Tags: nginx

I want to test this website for which I don't have a domain yet, and wanted to be able to access it via something like this:

`http://123.123.123.123/testsite`

I thought that on my testsite.conf file I could just do this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 123.123.123.123/testsite;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/testsite.com.access.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/testsite.com.error.log;

        root /var/www/testsite;
        index   index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
}
```

but it doesn't work... can anyone point me to the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation !

The [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) directive must not contain an URI part as it matches against the HTTP **Host** header.

Adapt your path and you [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) block to match `/test` instead of `/`.

Comment: And where do I put the log commands? inside the location block? Imagine I might want to have more than one rules like this. Thanks

Comment: @JoaoLeal Why do you want to duplicate this ? Just set [`access_log`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) in the http block scope and [`error_log`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) in the main block scope (in nginx.conf).